# rsync error (code 12) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.3] on Mac OS

Tags: macos, ssh, rsync

I'm trying to do a rsync network copy. I'm using homebrew's latest version of rsync. Both source and dest terminals show:

```
$ which rsync
/usr/local/bin/rsync
$ rsync --version
rsync  version 3.1.3  protocol version 31
```

I can successfully `scp` a file from the src to dest with:

```
scp /Users/me/file.txt me@host.local:/Users/me/
```

However if I try the same with rsync:

```
rsync -avihX --progress --stats /Users/me/file.txt me@host.local:/Users/me/
```

I get the following error:

```
rsync: on remote machine: -vlogDtpXre.iLsfxC: unknown option
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-52.200.1/rsync/main.c(1337) [server=2.6.9]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.3]
```

I've seen other post here and most say it's either a bad file path or non-matching rsync versions on destination terminal, both of which I've rules out.

Comment: That "[server=2.6.9]" message implies you *are* getting a version mismatch. Try adding `--rsync-path=/usr/local/bin/rsync` (or whatever the appropriate path for rsync v3.1.3 is).

Comment: That worked a treat, thanks @Gordon Davisson! Post an answer so mark it as answered :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That "[server=2.6.9]" part of the message implies you *are* getting a version mismatch. I'm not sure exactly how it sends the `rsync` command to the remote end, but it doesn't always use the same `PATH` (and hence version) that you get interactively. Try adding `--rsync-path=/usr/local/bin/rsync` (or whatever the appropriate path for rsync v3.1.3 is on the remote computer) to force it to use the right version.