# Run Targets with SSH server and rsync in IntelliJ (Windows 10)

Tags: intellij-idea, ssh, rsync

I am trying to run a java application on my server. The SSH connection works correctly and I can run programs without any problem.

However, enabling rsync, I am not able to run my programs:
I am trying to run a java application on my server. The SSH connection works correctly and I can run programs without any problem.

However, activating rsync, I am not able to run my programs:

```
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(235) [sender=3.1.3]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(228) [Receiver=3.2.3]
```

Rsync is correctly installed and I can use it from the powershell.
I have three ssh programas, Git, System32 and rsync one, I added this last one to the path and remove the others. Error still the same.

I have not found any documentations that fix my error. Any suggestion of what is going on?

Comment: `error in rsync protocol data stream` - have you re-login after changing the PATH?

Comment: Where do you get this error? Any more information in the [idea.log](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html#logs-directory) file?

Comment: @Andrey what should I have changed of the path? I just added ssh of rsync.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56721780/2000323). Such an issue can be caused by the rsync version mismatch between remote and local.

Comment: Please report the issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with idea.log file (Help | Show Log in ... action). Make also sure to try the version from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/